«Dream and believe» in Latin
I want to get a tattoo in Latin. I already have one but for another, my knowledge is not enough to translate correctly. The text I want is:

“Dream and believe”

Just to clarify, the phrase does not refer to sleeping and imagining things. Rather, it is about setting goals for yourself and having faith in your ability to achieve them.
Both words should be verbs.
I found 'Aspire et Crede', but I am not sure if it's the correct version.

As a quick feedback: What you found is not correct. Please don't put it into your skin. Or anywhere else for that matter... If you get an answer here, please wait a while to see what other users think of it and whether there will be other answers. Give it at least a couple of days.

Do you know how to say this phrase correctly?

You need two verbs: "to dream" and "to believe".
There are options for both, but credere is the standard choice for the latter and somniare is probably the best fit for the former.
See this question and its answer for a discussion on what somniare and some options mean.
You need these verbs in an imperative form.
In Latin, unlike in English, you have to know how many people you are ordering.
In the singular they would be crede et somnia and in the plural credite et somniate.
The word et may be replaced with the ampersand &, depending on what style or era you are aiming at.
Please consult any of the several good online Latin dictionaries to see whether these words fit your purpose.
They may be listed as credere & somniare or credo & somnio if you look them up in Latin.
If you find a verb that seems appropriate — based on a dictionary or its appearance somewhere that you wish to emulate — you can ask us to help find the correct form.
Latin and English verbs don't always have clean one-to-one correspondences, so there might not be anything you could call the correct translation.
